# How to generate different random values across each executors in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am not sure even if this is possible, but would like to ask the community .

I am generating a random string and then I am using this value to create a tag in an XML file. there are 2 ways that I am able to do this. either generate the random value before calling  map partition and then all xml's have the same value or create the random value within map partition which results in a different value for each XML..

I would like to know that is there a way that a random value if generated for each executor and then all the tasks assigned to that executor uses that value. So that I will end up having `n` random values for `n` executors(i.e, 10 executor instances ==  10 random values)

Comment: have u tried `monotonically_increasing_id`?

Comment: I don't want to use any spark functions here. I have a custom random string generator

Comment: Have you tried getting number of executors using `sc.statusTracker.getExecutorInfos`, and create a method that uses this returned number ?

Comment: Used `SparkEnv.get().executorId() ` within map partitions to achieve the solution